# Redundancy with basis vectors for $T_pM^\mathbb C \cong T_pM^{1,0} \oplus T_pM^{0,1}$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-manifolds

I've found out that the primary motivation for complexifying the tangent bundle is to enable its decomposition into the eigenspaces $\pm i$ of $J$. This decomposition facilitates the splitting of the bundle into holomorphic and antiholomorphic components. For the complexified tangent space $T_pM^\mathbb C$, we have a complex basis given by $\{\partial/\partial x_1,\dots, \partial/\partial x_n, \partial/\partial y_1,\dots, \partial/\partial y_n\}$. Given that $T_pM^\mathbb C \cong T_pM^{1,0} \oplus T_pM^{0,1}$, the isomorphisms can be represented as:
\begin{align*}
    T_pM &\to T_pM^{1,0}, \ v \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(v-iJv) \\
    T_pM &\to T_pM^{0,1}, \ v \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(v+iJv).
\end{align*}

Next I wanted to show that under these isomorphisms we can map the basis $$\{\partial/\partial x_1,\dots, \partial/\partial x_n, \partial/\partial x_y,\dots, \partial/\partial y_n\}$$ to the basis $$\{\partial/\partial z_1,\dots, \partial/\partial z_n, \partial/\partial \bar{z}_1,\dots, \partial/\partial \bar{z}_n\}$$ but I get some redundancy. For the first map $T_pM \to T_pM^{1,0}, \ v \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(v-iJv)$ we have \begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} &\mapsto \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} - iJ\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial z_j} \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} &\mapsto \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} - iJ\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} + i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right)
\end{align*}

and here $\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}$ doesn't map to either $\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j}$ or $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}_j}$.

Similarly for the map $T_pM \to T_pM^{0,1}, \ v \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(v+iJv)$ we have

\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} &\mapsto \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} + iJ\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} + i\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}_j} \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} &\mapsto \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} + iJ\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right)
\end{align*}

but again $\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}$ doesn't map to a corresponding basis element. Could anyone help me out why?

---

**Edit**: Does the following work out properly with the differences regarding complex and real bases? Since $T_pM^\mathbb C \cong T_pM^{1,0} \oplus T_pM^{0,1}$ we can use the isomorphisms \begin{align*}
    T_pM &\to T_pM^{1,0}, \ v \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(v-iJv) \\
    T_pM &\to T_pM^{0,1}, \ v \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(v+iJv)
\end{align*}
to send the real basis $\left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}, \dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y_1}, \dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial y_n} \right\}$ of $T_pM$ to \begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} &\mapsto \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} - iJ\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial z_j} \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} &\mapsto \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} - iJ\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} + i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right) = i\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j}
\end{align*}

giving $T_pM^{1,0}$ a real basis $\left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial z_1}, \dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial z_n}, i\frac{\partial}{\partial z_1}, \dots, i\frac{\partial}{\partial z_n} \right\}$ and a complex basis $\left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial z_1}, \dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial z_n}\right\}$. In a similar manner we send the real basis of $T_pM$ to $T_pM^{0,1}$ by  \begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} &\mapsto \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} + iJ\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} + i\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}_j} \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} &\mapsto \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} + iJ\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right) = -i\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}_j}
\end{align*}

which gives $T_pM^{0,1}$ a real basis $\left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial z_1}, \dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial z_n}, -i\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}_1}, \dots, -i\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}_n} \right\}$ and a complex basis $\left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}_1}, \dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}_n}\right\}$.

Comment: How is $J$ defined?

Comment: It's given by $J\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}$  and $J\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}\right) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}.$ @Filippo

Comment: So $J$ is only defined locally?

Comment: $M$ is a complex manifold and $J$ is the natural a.c.s defined on a chart $\varphi : U \to \varphi(U) \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ by $J = d\varphi^{-1} \circ J_{\mathbb{R}^{2n}} \circ d\varphi$ which we can extend to all of $M$ as since it's independent of the choice of the chart. @Filippo

Comment: I see, thank you for the introduction to complex manifolds! :D

Answer (score 1):

The formulae you have derive show that under the first map $\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}$ maps to $i\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j}$ while under the second map it maps to $-i\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z_j}$, which is consistent with the fact that the map to $T^{1,0}M$ is complex linear while the map to $T^{0,1}M$ is conjugate linear. You also have to keep in mind that you start from a real basis of $T_p M$ while the $ \frac{\partial}{\partial z_j}$ form a complex basis for $T^{1,0}M$. (And by definition, the vectors $\frac{\partial}{\partial X_j}$ do form a $\mathbb C$-basis for $T_pM$, so they should be mapped to a $\mathbb C$-basis of $T^{1,0}M$.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm starting with a complex basis $\{\partial/\partial x_1,\dots, \partial/\partial x_n, \partial/\partial y_1,\dots, \partial/\partial y_n\}$ for $T_pM$, what you are saying is that I would end up with $$\{\partial/\partial z_1,\dots, \partial/\partial z_n, i\partial/\partial z_1,\dots, i\partial/\partial z_n, \partial/\partial \bar{z}_1,\dots, \partial/\partial \bar{z}_1,-i\partial/\partial \bar{z}_1,\dots, -i\partial/\partial \bar{z}_1\}$$ which would mean that $T_pM^\mathbb{C}$ is $4n$ dimensional? @andreas-cap

Comment: @Victor That is not a *complex* basis for $T_pM$, it is a *real* basis for $T_pM$.

Comment: @quaere-verum I made an edit regarding this issue. If $\{\partial/\partial x_1,\dots, \partial/\partial x_n, \partial/\partial y_1,\dots, \partial/\partial y_n\}$ is a real basis for $T_pM$, then we can also treat it as a complex base for $T_pM^{\mathbb{C}}$.

Comment: @Victor Yes, that is not something I would dispute.

Comment: Yes that was a mistake on my part for not seeing that Andreas wrote $T_pM$ instead of $T_pM^{\mathbb{C}}$. Is the edit I made more or less correct? I'm unsure about the negative sign on the latter part. @QuaereVerum

Comment: @Victor Your edit looks correct to me, yes.